# Google LAMP trying to update sudo

Tags: apt, sudo, lamp, update

I was trying to update sudo on my LAMP cloud server at Google, but to no avail it seems.

Doing sudo apt update, then sudo apt install --only-upgrade sudo if finds the same sudo as on the system: Get:1 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main sudo amd64 1.8.10p3-1+deb8u7 [856 kB]

Checking apt-cache policy sudo, I get:
sudo:
Installed: 1.8.10p3-1+deb8u7
Candidate: 1.8.10p3-1+deb8u7
Version table:
*** 1.8.10p3-1+deb8u7 0
500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
1.8.10p3-1+deb8u5 0
500 http://deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
500 http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages

I don't want to do a sudo apt upgrade of the system, as I've now experienced two machines breaking from it lately and I don't want to break my server. What can I do to update the sudo package? I've tried finding a deb package, but can't find a URL to download it for manual installation.

Comment: Your Debian version is far past its end of life date and no longer receives updates of any sort. You should have upgraded to a currently supported release already. You should not upgrade in place when using Google Cloud; instead create new VM instances with current operating systems and migrate your applications to them.

Comment: Ok, is there an option to migrate everything or I have to set up a completely new LAMP VM and reconfigure/move databases etc ?